# Windows Store App Standard styles vs. Windows store App Guidelines for Fonts

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm developing my first Windows store app, and I have an issue with styles. Any new Windows store app project in VS 2012 has a StandardStyles.xaml resources dictionary. This resources dictionary contais a lot of styles for all the textblock controls, but this styles aren't consistencies with the styles in the [Windows Store App Guidelines For Fonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700394.aspx). For example
- HeaderTextStyle is a style for page headers in StandardStyles.xaml and it has a FontSize setter with value=56;
- Page header, in Windows Store App Guidelines for Font, has the FontSize property value equal to 42

What is the right choise?

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of units.  It is a 42pt font, which is 56 pixels.

Here is a blog post that might help: http://w8isms.blogspot.com/2012/06/metro-fonts-points-pixels.html